# No Location Provider Found in Lollipop and Marshmallow

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I working with a project to find the address using latitude and longitude. I got answer in Jellybean but when comes to Lollipop and Marshmallow it only showing latitude and longitude, not getting address. It shows location provider is not found. Is there any error in my code?

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    mprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if (mprovider != null && !mprovider.equals("")) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mprovider);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mprovider,5000, 0,this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        if (location != null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location Provider Found Check Your Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    longitude.setText("Current Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    latitude.setText("Current Latitude:" + location.getLatitude());
    Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    // String mylocation;
    try {
        List < Address > addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
            address1.setText(address);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            textViewCity.setText(city);
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            textViewState.setText(state);
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            textViewCountry.setText(country);
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            textViewPostal.setText(postalCode);
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

            System.out.println("Address >> " + address + " " +city+ " \n" + state + " \n" + country+ "\n"+postalCode+ "\n"+knownName);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that the stuff with the Geocoder is not working? Then why didnt you tell? What is Geocoder?

Comment: `It shows`. What is 'it'?

Comment: `catch (IOException e)`. Place a log statement in the catch block. And set e.getMessage() in a text view. Only then the user knows what happens.

Comment: are you sure you are getting lattitude and logngitude with this code in marshmellow.

Comment: yes. I am getting latitude and longitude in marshmallow emulator, but not in real device

Comment: that is a problem.. bcz this code will not work in marshmellow. you will never get lat lag with this code. but i have a solution..wait..

Comment: @ greenapps  sorry "it" means in my logcat shows that provider doesn't exist: network

Comment: @sagarChavada ok..

Answer (score 1):

add this class.

```
public class SingleShotLocationProvider {

    public static interface LocationCallback {
        public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location);
    }

    // calls back to calling thread, note this is for low grain: if you want higher precision, swap the
    // contents of the else and if. Also be sure to check gps permission/settings are allowed.
    // call usually takes <10ms
    public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }
            }, null);
      } else {
          boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
          if (isGPSEnabled) {
              Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
              criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
              locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                      callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                  }

                  @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
                  @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
                  @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
              }, null);
          }
      }
  }


  // consider returning Location instead of this dummy wrapper class
  public static class GPSCoordinates {
      public float longitude = -1;
      public float latitude = -1;

      public GPSCoordinates(float theLatitude, float theLongitude) {
          longitude = theLongitude;
          latitude = theLatitude;
      }

      public GPSCoordinates(double theLatitude, double theLongitude) {
          longitude = (float) theLongitude;
          latitude = (float) theLatitude;
      }
  }  
}
```

and use like this:

```
SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(getActivity(),
                            new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onNewLocationAvailable(SingleShotLocationProvider.GPSCoordinates location) {
                                    lat = location.latitude;
                                    lag = location.longitude;
                                }
                            });
```

here you can get lat - lag if your device location is enable. so also check that is enable or not.

```
if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    showEnableLocationDialog();
                } else {
                                    SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(getActivity(),
                            new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onNewLocationAvailable(SingleShotLocationProvider.GPSCoordinates location) {
                                    lat = location.latitude;
                                    lag = location.longitude;
                                }
                            });
                }



public void showEnableLocationDialog() {
        final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builderDialog.setTitle("Enable Location");
        builderDialog.setMessage("Please enable location for near by search");
        builderDialog.setPositiveButton("Enable",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });
        builderDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        //fetchImages();
                    }
                });
        android.app.AlertDialog alert = builderDialog.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

and i hope you are asking run-time permission for location first. otherwise you will never get location.